# Find a substring from a structured string using startswith and index

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that finds a substring (can be a number or anything else) from a structured string.
The string is structured (2 possibilites) like:

1. string = `'1x substring 3x 4x'`
2. string = `'4x 3x substring 1x'`

   - `x` can be any character
   - `substring` formatted like `'pos. 2'`

The normal case works with the code below, but now I would also like to consider the special cases.I have tried: `i.startswith(('3','4'))`, but that didn't work.

string 1-8 should explain the logic using a simple example.

string 9-10 shows a complex example.
The code should extract the substrings at Pos 2, 5 and Pos 7.

I hope you can help to find a solution for all strings / special cases to get `clean : 80` for all cases. `:-)`

string 9:

`clean:  pos2 ='$80'    pos5 = '75.000 kg'   pos7 = '22 sec'`

string 10:

`clean: pos2 = '$67'   pos5 = '69.000kg'    pos7 = '12sec'`

```
#str1-8 easy example strings

#normal string
str1 = '1x 80 3x 4x'
str2 = '4x 3x 80 1x'

# missing number/pos. 3
str3 = '1x 80 4x '
str4 = '4x 80 1x'
str3a = '1. A  $67  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result: `clean: pos2 = '$67'   pos5 = '69.000kg'    pos7 = '12sec'` 
str4a = '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b  $80 1b'
result: `clean:  pos2 ='$80'    pos5 = '75.000 kg'   pos7 = '22 sec'` 

# missing number/pos. 1, => number is at the start or end of the string
str5 = '80 3x 4x'
str6 = '4x 3x 80'
str5a =  '10 Mrd 3: A 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D ' 
result: clean: pos2= 10 Mrd, pos5= 50,379 pos7=7:19 (or just 19 in raw string without 7: if its easier)
str6a = '  9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a 3 b 50 '
result: clean: pos2= 50, pos5= 60000 pos7=10 

# Optional (rare case)
# missing number/pos. 1 and 3
str7 = '80 4x'
str8 = '4x 80'
str7a = '10 Mrd 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D ' 
result: clean: pos2= 10 Mrd, pos5= 50,379 pos7=7:19 (or just 19 in raw string without 7: if its easier)
str8a = ' 9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a  50 '
result: clean: pos2= 50, pos5= 60000 pos7=10 
# complex realistic strings
str9 = '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b 3b  $80 1b'
str10 = '1. A  $67  3. A  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'

# missing number/pos. 4 or 6 (Pos6 Optional, cause thats difficult i guess)
str11 = '1. A  $67  3. A    69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result: `clean: pos2 = '$67'   pos5 = '69.000kg'    pos7 = '12sec'
str12 = '1. A  $67  3. A  4a  69.000kg   12sec  8. B  9. B'
result: `clean: pos2 = '$67'   pos5 = '69.000kg'    pos7 = '12sec'

x_list = [str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7,str8, str9, str10, str11,str12]

for x in x_list:
    print ("raw             "+x)
    
    values = ['1x', '3x', '4x']
    try:
        for i in values:
            if i.startswith('3') :
                foo=i

            if  i.startswith("1") :
                baa=i 

            start=x.index(foo) + len( foo )
            end=x.index(baa)   

            if start < end:
                pass
                number = x[start:end].strip(' ')


            else:
                start=x.index(baa) + len( baa )
                end=x.index(foo) 
        
                number = x[start:end].strip(' ')
            
    except: 
        number ='0' 
    
    print ("clean           "+number)
```

Output:

```
raw             1x 80 3x 4x
clean           80
raw             4x 3x 80 1x
clean           80
raw             1x 80 4x 
clean           0
raw             4x 80 1x
clean           0
raw             80 3x 4x
clean           0
raw             4x 3x 80
clean           0
raw             80 4x
clean           0
raw             4x 80
clean           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this look like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
>>> import re
>>> text="""1x 80 3x 4x
4x 3x 80 1x
1x 80 4x
4x 80 1x
80 3x 4x
4x 3x 80
80 4x
4x 80""".splitlines()
>>> text
['1x 80 3x 4x', '4x 3x 80 1x', '1x 80 4x', '4x 80 1x', '80 3x 4x', '4x 3x 80', '80 4x', '4x 80']
>>> for t in text:
        res = re.search("((1|4). )?(3. )?(?P<result>[^ ]+)(3. )?((1|4). )?",t)
        print(f"raw: {t!r}\nclean: {res['result']!r}")

    
raw: '1x 80 3x 4x'
clean: '80'
raw: '4x 3x 80 1x'
clean: '80'
raw: '1x 80 4x'
clean: '80'
raw: '4x 80 1x'
clean: '80'
raw: '80 3x 4x'
clean: '80'
raw: '4x 3x 80'
clean: '80'
raw: '80 4x'
clean: '80'
raw: '4x 80'
clean: '80'
>>>
```

here `.` represent any character, `(a|b)` is a or b for expresions a and b, `(...)?` means that the inside is optional so `((1|4). )?` mean 1 or 4 alongside one character plus one space and is optional, similar for the others, and for `(?P<result>[^ ]+)`, `(?P<name>...)` means that is a group named *name*, `[^ ]` is any character but space and the plus sign is that we want one or more

UPDATE:

```
import re

POSRE = "(?P<pos>(?:[1-9](?:[\.\: ] ?)?[a-zA-Z](?: |$)))"

def extrator(rawtext):
    result = filter(None,map(str.strip,re.split(POSRE,rawtext)))
    result = [(x,int(x[0]) if re.match(POSRE,x) else None) for x in result]
    pos=[n for x,n in result if n]
    if sorted(pos)!=pos:
        result = list(reversed(result))
    final = [x for x,p in result if p is None]
    if len(final)==2 and 6 not in pos:
        a,b = final
        final = [a,*b.split()]
    elif len(final)<3:
        final.extend([None]*(3-len(final)))
    return final
```

So the main thing here is identify those position marker which structure is know, for that I device that regular expression were we check if its a single number (`[1-9]`) optionally follow by a `.` or `:` or   (`(?:[\.\: ] ?)?`) then a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`) and then another space or the end of the string (`(?: |$)`). The `(?:...)` means that is a not capturing group, for more detail on those check the documentation linked above...

We use that in `re.split` to split the text into its matching and not matching parts which are then strip out of their surrounding spaces characters and filter out those that turn out to be empty.

We follow that by identifying what is their position if they are a matching string or None if not.

Then is just a couple simple check, like in what order they came and reversed it if needed so we always return in the same order and extract what we need in `final`, check for the final case and adjust accordingly and done.

and a little test

```
text="""1. A  $67  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B
9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b  $80 1b
10 Mrd 3: A 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D
9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a 3 b 50
10 Mrd 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D
9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a  50
9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b 3b  $80 1b
1. A  $67  3. A    69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B
1. A  $67  3. A  4a  69.000kg   12sec  8. B  9. B
9a 8b 6b 4a 3 b 50 1b""".splitlines()

for t in text:
    print(f"raw: {t!r}\nresult: ",extrator(t) )
    print()
```

which give us

```
raw: '1. A  $67  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  ['$67', '69.000kg', '12sec']

raw: '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b  $80 1b'
result:  ['$80', '75.000kg', '22 sec']

raw: '10 Mrd 3: A 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D'
result:  ['10 Mrd', '50 .379', '7:19']

raw: '9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a 3 b 50'
result:  ['50', '60000', '10']

raw: '10 Mrd 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D'
result:  ['10 Mrd', '50 .379', '7:19']

raw: '9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a  50'
result:  ['50', '60000', '10']

raw: '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b 3b  $80 1b'
result:  ['$80', '75.000kg', '22 sec']

raw: '1. A  $67  3. A    69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  ['$67', '69.000kg', '12sec']

raw: '1. A  $67  3. A  4a  69.000kg   12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  ['$67', '69.000kg', '12sec']

raw: '9a 8b 6b 4a 3 b 50 1b'
result:  ['50', None, None]
```

**UPDATE 2**

here is a version which identify which one is the data we got given a couple of assumption such as:

- there is only position markers and data, the data is only a positions 2, 5 and 7
- the previous regular expression can identify those position markers
- any of those can go missing
- and there is no space characters in the data so in case any of the relevant positions markers is missing and less data than expect is found then one of those may be group in one of the data points extracted and thus can be safely `str.split`, if that is not the case, adjust in those parts accordingly.

this result in a rather lengthy case by case check I hope is self explanatory and return a dictionary that said who is who.

surely this can be refined, but no refinement had come to mind.

```
def extrator(rawtext):
    fil  = filter(None,map(str.strip,re.split(POSRE,rawtext)))
    proc = [(x,int(x[0]) if re.match(POSRE,x) else None) for x in fil] #process raw data
    pos  = [p for x,p in proc if p is not None ] #position markers presents
    if sorted(pos)!=pos:
        proc = list(reversed(proc))        
    data = [x for x,p in proc if p is None]
    pos = {p:i for i,(x,p) in enumerate(proc) if p is not None } #pos marker:index of it
    #print(f"{proc=}")
    if len(data)==3:
        return dict(zip((2,5,7),data))
    #from here, a,b,c will represent data in position 2,5 and 7 respectively
    elif len(data)==2:
        a,b = data
        #c = None
        if 3 in pos or 4 in pos:
            if 6 in pos:
                #one of 2, 5 or 7 is missing
                i = proc.index( (a,None) )
                i34 = pos[3] if 3 in pos else pos[4]
                if i < i34:
                    #a is 2, b is 5 or 7
                    j = proc.index( (b,None) )
                    if j < pos[6]:
                        #7 is missing
                        c = None
                    else:
                        #5 is missing
                        b,c = None,b
                else:
                    #2 is missing, a is 5 thus b is 7
                    a,b,c = None,a,b
            else:
                #a is 2, b may be 5 or 7 or both
                t = b.split()
                if len(t) == 2:
                    #b was both
                    b,c = t
                elif len(t) == 1:
                    #b is 5 or 7
                    print("either 5 or 7 is missing, picked 7 as missing")
                    c = None
                else:
                    #b was split into more than 2 parts
                    raise RuntimeError("unknow case 1")
        else:
            #3 and 4 are missing
            if 6 in pos:
                #a may be 2 or 5 or both, b is 7
                c = b
                t = a.split()
                if len(t) == 2:
                    #a was both
                    a,b = t
                elif len(t) == 1:
                    print("either 2 or 5 is missing, picked 5 as missing")
                    b = None
                else:
                    #a was split into more than 2 parts
                    raise RuntimeError("unknow case 2")
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Fatal error: 2 data points with no marker in between")
        return dict(zip((2,5,7),(a,b,c)))
    elif len(data)==1:
        a = data[0]
        i = proc.index( (a,None) )
        #b,c = None, None
        if 3 in pos or 4 in pos:
            i34 = pos[3] if 3 in pos else pos[4]
            if 6 in pos:
                #only one of 2,5 or 7 are present
                if i < i34:
                    #a is 2 the rest is missing
                    b,c = None, None
                elif i < pos[6]:
                    #a is 5
                    a,b,c = None, a, None
                else:
                    #a is 7
                    a,b,c = None, None, a 
            else:
                #a is 2 or a is 5 or 7 or both
                if i < i34:
                    #a is 2, the rest is missing
                    b,c = None, None
                else:
                    #2 is missing, a is 5 or 7 or both 
                    a,b = None, a
                    t = b.split()
                    if len(t) == 2:
                        b,c = t
                    elif len(t) == 1:
                        print("either 5 or 7 is missing, picked 7 as missing")
                        c = None
                    else:
                        raise RuntimeError("unknow case 3")
        else:
            #3 and 4 are missing
            if 6 in pos:
                if pos[6] < i:
                    #a is 7, the rest is missing
                    a,b,c = None, None, a
                else:
                    #7 is missing, a is 2 or 5 or both
                    c = None
                    t = a.split()
                    if len(t) == 2:
                        a,b = t
                    elif len(t) == 1:
                        print("either 2 or 5 is missing, picked 5 as missing")
                        b = None
                    else:
                        raise RuntimeError("unknow case 4")
            else:
                #a is 2, 5 or 7 or any combination of them
                t = a.split()
                if len(t) == 3:
                    a,b,c = t
                elif len(t) == 2:
                    print("one of 2, 5 or 7 is missing, picked 7 as missing")
                    a,b = t
                    c = None
                elif len(t) == 1:
                    print("only one of 2, 5 or 7 is present, picked 2 as present")
                    b,c = None, None
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError("unknow case 5")
        return dict(zip((2,5,7),(a,b,c)))
    elif len(data) == 0:
        return dict.fromkeys( (2,5,7) )
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("unknow case 6: more than 3 data points")


def test():
    text="""1. A  $67  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B
9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b  $80 1b
10 Mrd 3: A 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D
9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a 3 b 50
10 Mrd 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D
9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a  50
9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b 3b  $80 1b
1. A  $67  3. A    69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B
1. A  $67  3. A  4a  69.000kg   12sec  8. B  9. B
9a 8b 6b 4a 3 b 50 1b
9 a 8b 6 b 55 4a 3 b 1b
9a 8:b 777 6 b 4.a 3 b 1b
9a 8:b 777 6 b 4.a 3 b 55 1b
""".splitlines()

    for t in text:
        print(f"raw: {t!r}\nresult: ",extrator(t) )
        print()
```

output

```
>>> test()
raw: '1. A  $67  4. A  69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  {2: '$67', 5: '69.000kg', 7: '12sec'}

raw: '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b  $80 1b'
result:  {2: '$80', 5: '75.000kg', 7: '22 sec'}

raw: '10 Mrd 3: A 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D'
result:  {2: '10 Mrd', 5: '50 .379', 7: '7:19'}

raw: '9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a 3 b 50'
result:  {2: '50', 5: '60000', 7: '10'}

raw: '10 Mrd 4: A  50 .379 6: A   7:19   8: B 9: D'
result:  {2: '10 Mrd', 5: '50 .379', 7: '7:19'}

raw: '9a 8b 10 6b 60000 4a  50'
result:  {2: '50', 5: '60000', 7: '10'}

raw: '9B 8B 22 sec 6A 75.000kg 4b 3b  $80 1b'
result:  {2: '$80', 5: '75.000kg', 7: '22 sec'}

raw: '1. A  $67  3. A    69.000kg  6. A  12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  {2: '$67', 5: '69.000kg', 7: '12sec'}

raw: '1. A  $67  3. A  4a  69.000kg   12sec  8. B  9. B'
result:  {2: '$67', 5: '69.000kg', 7: '12sec'}

raw: '9a 8b 6b 4a 3 b 50 1b'
result:  {2: '50', 5: None, 7: None}

raw: '9 a 8b 6 b 55 4a 3 b 1b'
result:  {2: None, 5: '55', 7: None}

raw: '9a 8:b 777 6 b 4.a 3 b 1b'
result:  {2: None, 5: None, 7: '777'}

raw: '9a 8:b 777 6 b 4.a 3 b 55 1b'
result:  {2: '55', 5: None, 7: '777'}

>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your work. I seems that my example was to easy to show what I need. Sorry for it. I add string 9 and 10 as realistic strings in my question to make it more clear. I extracted the ```values = ['1x', '3x', '4x']``` one step before. Thats why Iam using startswith() to compare it with the string. Maybe it is not the best way. But for me it's close to the final solution.with taking into account the realistic strings. :-)

Comment: ok, and what is the result you want to get from the realistic examples?

Comment: ok I added the result of the realistic examples. Be in mind it should work like. For String Pos: 2 => If pos.3 is missing use pos 4 as indication. Or is pos 1 missing use start/end of the string. Optional(if its possible): For String Pos. 5 similar: => If pos.4 is missing use pos 3 as indication or  If pos.6 is missing use pos.7. (But I guess thats hard to solve). Thank you for your time

Comment: can you also add realistic examples for each of the other cases and their desire result? later I will try another go at it

Comment: Wow, that's just impressive. Really a great work. Thank you very much. I didn't think,   the code can be that robust. Perfect.. Maybe one icing on the cake: It is possible to get just '0' or none, if the required substring is missing. Like '9a 8b 6b 4a 3 b 50 1b' => result: '50 0 0'

Comment: sure that is possible, but you should be able to adjust it to add those minor detail yourself, you can check for the len(final) and append "0" or None accordingly in similar way as to how I check for len(final)==2 and then check if 6 is the missing position marker. Well, I added that it

Comment: if you need to identify which one is each, you can use the result list, which contain the pairs (x, n) where were n will be None if x is not one of those position markers, so if its None is the thing you are looking for and you can know which one it is by their order of appearance and the other surrounding it

Comment: yes you are right. I need to identify which one is each. Like result: ($50  0  75.000kg  0 ) if the values are missing. But I get your idea. I have to analyse your code and need a bit time to find a solution. But again: Many thanks again for this great job. :-)

Comment: I have some trouble to get the desired result like  ($50 0 75.000kg 0 ) . Cause I'm not really able to check the previous and the next p item in a for loop. Hope you can me help me again:-) Something like : for x,p in result:
            if (1) < p < (3) and p is None:
                final.append(x)
            else:
                x = '0'
                final.append(x) is not really working

Comment: you can't compare None with numbers, but the main challenge here is that one or more of those can go missing even the one even the one that aren't one of this position markers so you have to check several cases there... so is necessary to exploit every patter you can find here, like: is the useful data always in position 2, 5 and 7 and no other position can have useful data? if so that can be used to identify each one, like for the first None you can ask if 3 or 4 are present if so then this one is 2, and so on with the question, but if you have 3 None no questions are necessary

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I am not able to implement it. The numerical values ​​are always in positions 2 5 and 7, which is fixed. But if position 3 or 4 is missing as an indicator and one of the numerical values ​​is in position 2 or 5, then it becomes really difficult. Maybe you can help me again and give me an example code for e.g. pos 2. showing how you would solve that? That be awesome.:-)

Comment: ok, I will give it some thought to it and I tell you later, there is a bunch of cases to consider... but for example if 3 and 4 are missing but 6 is present, then the data might contain both 2 and 5 so you can split it and act accordingly

Comment: basically get some cards or something and play out all combination, if you get 2 or less data points then two might be combined into one and need to be split, the only position marker that matter are 3 or 4 and 6 because those are the ones that get in between the data point to make up the splits with the regular expression

Comment: added version which said who is who

Comment: I'm speechless at the effort you made for it. I can't thank you enough for that. :-) I was afraid that the code would be so long and a little complicated, but that's exactly what the code is supposed to do :-) You also explained the steps really well. Really great job. Maybe I should send you a Christmas present for it :-). Thank you very very much. (PS: Just for information, an interesting case: If you enter 60s instead of 60sec, the code gets into trouble, it would be interesting to know why its doing this but no worries :-))

Comment: present are always welcome :) anyway, what is this problem you mention? As far as I can tell, there is no issue with "60s" vs "60sec" it pick it no problem... this code try identify who is who by their relative position only and arbitrarily pick one when it can't do that, if such picking is wrong, then just do the necessary modifications in order to fix it, those points of arbitrary choosing are alongside the prints

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you goals correctly, it seems to me like you are far over-complicating the process. I wrote a function which splits the input string to a list and checks whether each segment meets the formatting of `1x`, `2x`, or `3x`. Check it out and let me know if it's not what you need.

```py
# we use regex to check for matches with the format
import re

#list of strings
x_list = ["1x 80 3x 4x","4x 3x 80 1x"]
for x in x_list:
    print(find_substr(x))

def find_substr(x):
    # break on spaces into a list
    seg = x.split(" ")
    # check each word for the desired format
    for i in range(len(seg)):
        for j in [1,3,4]:
            if re.search(str(j)+".", seg[i]) is None:
                # this word does not fit the format, so it's the substring
                return seg
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.  that's a good objection.  but I made the code so complicated because the actual string is also much more complicated.  means: there are several substrings in different but defined positions.  In addition, the structure of the indicators varies, i.e.  1x can be '1a' or '1 a' or '1: a'.  only the number is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code up a little to be more readable. I didn't know if this is what you wanted but it works. Let me know if you have any questions. I would be happy to help

```
for x in x_list:
    print ("raw             "+x)

    try:
        # splits the string into a list, separating on spaces (e.g ['1x', '80', '3x', '4x'])
        y = x.split(" ")

        # a is the substring that you are checking in the list
        a = '80'
        if a in y:
            index = y.index(a)
            number = y[index]

    except: 
        number ='0' 
    
    print ("clean           "+number)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Please see my comment on the other answer.  Your code is good for the example.  But unfortunately I have a complicated string in reality.  I hope you can still find a solution.  Thank you for your efforts